# How Can I render my react components on the server without heavily modifying my existing app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

My server.js file is written in node and looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

// using webpack-dev-server and middleware in development environment
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
  var webpack = require('webpack');
  var config = require('./webpack.config');
  var compiler = webpack(config);

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
});

app.listen(PORT, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.info("Listening on port %s", PORT);
  }
});
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>what ever</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'/>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

My index.js file which includes my react router code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

/*----------- STYLESHEETS -----------*/
require('./assets/stylesheets/base.scss');

let history = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? browserHistory : hashHistory;
/*----------- ROUTE COMPONENTS -----------*/
import Home from './components/home';
import Company from './components/company';
import Features from './components/features';
import Help from './components/help';
import SignUp from './components/signup';
import Work from './components/work';
render((
  <Router history={history}>
    {/** ###### HOME ROUTE ###### */}
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
    <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
    <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
    {/** ###### END HOME ROUTES ###### */}
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am using webpack to build and include assets like sass and images. I was able to use [this](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example) tutorial to render a single page via the server, but it appeared with no css and images and it also appears to completely change the flow of the app in a way that doesn't seem good. Any examples of light weight simple apps not using 800000 different libraries that render on the server?

Comment: The "universal" example from redux might help you: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/universal. It's a simple app with server rendering, and it's easy to ignore the redux parts if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is Node doesn't know how to handle requiring your non js / json assets.

One solution supported out of the box by Webpack is to use [`target: 'node'`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) and [`output.libraryTarget: commonjs2`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) which will generate a bundle ready to be `require`d in Node.

You'll also want to look at the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract your CSS into a separate file, otherwise html will render un-styled until the JS has downloaded.

It get's a little more complicated when using React Router but there's some good documentation here - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar thing and found this blog useful. You should try following it too, it will be easy to setup, and get started with. [Server side rendering with react, node & express](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/server-side-rendering-react-node-express/)